# How I go to definitions of Laravel classes in visual studio code editor for windows?

Tags: laravel, visual-studio-code

I can't access the definition using ctrl+click. Even when I try using click+Go to definition it says no definition found.

Here I was trying to go to the main Statefulguard file by pressing F12

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\StatefulGuard;       

public function __construct(StatefulGuard $guard)    
{    
    $this->guard = $guard;    
}
```

[image: When I try going to the definition]

Comment: Have you opened the project folder or individual files?

Comment: I have opened the project folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a composer package designed to generate files that work in conjunction with an IDE plugin to help with definition-tracking for Laravel abstractions.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=georgykurian.laravel-ide-helper

Comment: IG it should work without any 3rd party package.

Answer (score 5):

**intelephense** like, if work for you ctrl + click go to definition

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client

other you can install **PHP namespace resover**. for import/set the classes to header.

Comment: This works for me, suddenly I was surprised I couldn't use the ctrl + click go to definition feature. I forgot I had uninstalled PHP intelephense extension, and after reinstalling it, it works again.